# Substitute outliers depending on quartile and group

Tags: r, outliers

I have the following data frame:

```
d = 
id group value
1  A     1
2  A     2
3  A     10
4  B     100
5  B     200
6  B     1000
```

I would like to replace those values above the 99% quartile with an NA depending on the group they belong. In this example would be observations (id) 3 and 6. So far I have this piece of code that does what I want but NOT depending on each group.

```
d[ d$value.TA < quantile(d$value, 0.99), 'value'] <- NA
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `group_by()` function from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- d %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(value.TA = ifelse(value < quantile(value, 0.99),
                           value, NA)) %>%
  ungroup()

> d    
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id  group value value.TA
  <int> <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1      A     1        1
2     2      A     2        2
3     3      A    10       NA
4     4      B   100      100
5     5      B   200      200
6     6      B  1000       NA
```

Data:

```
d <- data.frame(
  id = seq(1, 6),
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
  value = c(1,2,10,100,200,1000)
)
```